# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'ec2_privateIP' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this issue, but none have helped me resolved the issue.

I am attempting to connect my laravel project on my EC2 instance to my RDS instance.

I can successfully connect to the RDS instance and create tables when I use:

```
mysql -h ....rds.amazonaws.com -u cmadmin -p
```

However, I am currently getting the error below when I run `php artisan migrate`:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cmadmin'@'ec2_privateIP' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dbname_cm and table_name = migrations)


In Connector.php line 67:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cmadmin'@'ec2_privateIP' (using password: YES)
```

Here's an excerpt of the .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=generatedkey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=....rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname_cm
DB_USERNAME=cmadmin
DB_PASSWORD=rfL8zvXnMEzit02
```

Here's an excerpt of the config/database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'option'  => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path('/var/mysql-cert/dbname_cm-db.pem')
    ],
],
```

I even went as far as to add the following to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
    {
       Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

I have already ran:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache

PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
Laravel Framework 5.5.49
AWS RDS: MySQL 8.0.17

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+------------------------+----------------+
| USER()                 | CURRENT_USER() |
+------------------------+----------------+
| cmadmin@ec2_privateIP  | cmadmin@%      |
+------------------------+----------------+
```

```
mysql> show grants;
| Grants for cmadmin@% |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO `cmadmin`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION |
```

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| dbname_cm          |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding the code below in the database.php file

```
'mysql' = [
'sslmode' => 'require',
'options'   => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/certs/client-key.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/certs/client-cert.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/certs/ca.pem',
        )
],
```

Comment: I have same issue but I am not sure how to get those certificate and keys?

Answer (score 0):

````
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'option'  => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path('/var/mysql-cert/dbname_cm-db.pem')
    ],
],```

have you already try file this part `'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),` with `'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'cmadmin'),`

and of course the DB_PASSWORD part with your predefined password
````

Comment: Yes I have filled the database.php file with the database credentials as well